# problem in removing layer from map using openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i develop a filter in which a dropdown is pouplated with the layer attribute and the next dropdown populate on the basis of value selection of first dropdown. but the problem is when i select next value from first dropdown the layer of first value doesnot disappear. here is my code

```js
$.getJSON(
          'url',
          function (data) {
            loadFeatures(data);
          }
        );

        function loadFeatures(data) {
          // load vector source
          vector.getSource().addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data));
          vector.setStyle(null);
          var features = vector.getSource().getFeatures();
          // add select options
          $.each(features, function(i, v) {
            $('#countries').append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(v.get('Name')));
          });

          $('#countries').on('change', function() {
            var selected = $('#countries').val();
            value = $('#countries :selected').text();
        
             extent = vector.getSource().getFeatures()[selected];
            extent.setStyle(myStyle);
              var poly = extent.getGeometry().getExtent();
              
             var center=ol.extent.getCenter(poly);
            
             
             map.setView( new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',//or any projection you are using
    center: [center[0] , center[1]],//zoom to the center of your feature
    zoom: 7 //here you define the levelof zoom
 }));
 
 
 
          });
         
        }
```

the problem when i select country name from "countries" dropdown map does not remove first value layer.  i have tried layer.refresh(), layer.changed() etc but nothing works

Comment: To clear and/or refresh a vector layer you need `layer.getSource().clear()` or `layer.getSource().refresh()`

Comment: it has the same result it clear the layer totally including the shape file of selected feature

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you format your code properly and provide a stackblitz or similar. as it is it is not clear what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: sir! what u do not understand in the code. layers name populate into the countries dropdown user select one country name from the dropdown list